# How do i set a label on an issue using the JIRA SOAP API

Tags: soap, jira

Is there a way to set the "Labels" field for a ticket when creating or updating a JIRA ticket using the SOAP API? A search for "label" in the WSDL reveals nothing, and when getting a ticket using the API which I know has labels set, there is no indication in the result that a label exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no method to do this in JiraSoapService

http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html

~Matt

Comment: as a temporary workaround you can add a custom field with type label and then access over the custom fields bit of the Soap API

Answer (score 10):

You can update the label of an existing issue using the field id 'labels'. Here is the code I'm using (C#):

```
public void LabelIssue(string issueKey, string label)
{
    RemoteIssue issue = jiraSoapService.getIssue(token, issueKey);
    List<RemoteFieldValue> actionParams = new List<RemoteFieldValue>();
    RemoteFieldValue labels = new RemoteFieldValue { id = "labels", values = new string[] { label } };
    actionParams.Add(labels);
    jiraSoapService.updateIssue(token, issue.key, actionParams.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating custom field id 10041. I looked forever and I finally found it.

Here is sample code in python:

```
update_str = [{"id": "customfield_10041", "values":["my_label"]}]
ret = jira_handle.service.updateIssue(auth, key, update_str)
```

Hope that helps!!